# Can't connect to Firebase Database temporarily

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Sometimes when I load my app, I just can't seem to connect to Realtime Database using REST APIs. This is only a problem I have been having very recently; it mostly always works but sometimes, randomly, just cannot resolve the destination host.

During one of these times, I have tried using my browser to go to the Firebase Realtime Database page manually: https://project-id.firebaseio.com/
This page should redirect me to my project console. Instead, it just returned a 404.

So I think the problem has nothing to do with my code but it is something Firebase Server-side... what could be the problem?

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you troubleshoot without seeing something that we can run ourselves to reproduce the problem, or at least some code and logging output of when the problem occurs. If those are not feasible, consider [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they can look at your project to look for anomalies.

Comment: Thank you, I did. I will update this question when I get a response